# Django unit tests: Can I specify default label/location?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, python-unittest, django-unittest

I know that when I run

```
$ ./manage.py test
```

then it will discover tests in any file named `test*.py` under the current working directory.

I also know that I can specify a test label like this:

```
$ ./manage.py test animals.tests
```

Then all the tests in the `animals.tests` module will be run.

Another option is to specify a directory like this:

```
$ ./manage.py test animals/
```

And then all the tests in the `animals/` directory will be discovered and run.
(The examples above are from the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/testing/overview/#running-tests).)

I'd like to know if there is a way to specify a default test label to be tested or a directory to be used for tests discovery.

Let's say I'd like to run the tests in `animals/` directory by default (i.e. if not specified otherwise). Then the following two commands would be equal:

```
$ ./manage.py test

$ ./manage.py test animals/
```

Although I would still like to be able to run another tests like this:

```
$ ./manage.py test people/
```

Thank you.

P.S. I know that I could redefine the `test` management command but I'd rather avoid doing this. I'm looking for a cleaner solution - such as a configuration option etc.

Comment: Why do you want to change the default behavior at all?

Comment: I need to have my tests in a separate directory, where the default `./manage.py test` doesn't find them. I can specify the directory manually but for convenience I would like to set this as default.